# PHPExcel and convert to HTML

Tags: php, html, converters, phpexcel

I want to create a preview of existing excel file(xlsm,xlsx) in browser. I using phpExcel to convert excel file to html file and after this take HTML code from it but after all this converters the tabs (worksheets) disappear and I cannot go to next one, how may I repair this?.

```
public function createHtmlPreview($path)
{        
    $file = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $path).'.htm';

    $objPHPExcelReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelReader->load($path);


    $objPHPExcelWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'HTML');
    $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelWriter->save($file);

    $html = new \DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTMLFile($file);
    unlink($file);

    return $html->saveHTML();
    //return $file;
}
```

Comment: `$objPHPExcelWriter->writeAllSheets();`

Comment: But why are you saving with PHPExcel, loading using DOM then saving again?

Comment: $objPHPExcelWriter->writeAllSheets();
work but all worksheets are below first sheet not in tabs
I'm using DOM because i just wanna HTML code to display in my page

Comment: Then why not save directly to `php://output` rather than go through all the overheads of save to disk, reload from disk, delete from disk, send to `php://output`